DataTable control ignoring SharePoint URL column text value?
I'm using Datatable control in Power Apps an would like to use a literal text for my hyperlink in a column. The URL link is in SharePoint.
When I change the text to use "Link" and then save it doesn't save and publish and it goes back displaying the actual URL.
See screenshot below:


What is the column/data type of "Teams" column in SharePoint list?

Hi Ganesh, Its just string "Single line of Text"

Try solution given below.

Did you try below solution?

Try these formulas for your Teams_Column1 in data table control:
Text:
Substitute(ThisItem.Teams,ThisItem.Teams,"Link")

OnSelect:
Launch(DataTable1.Selected.Teams,{},LaunchTarget.New)



Output (Play mode):

